# Received no welcome email, no password reset email, and no way to reset password for Community user

Tags: community, customer-community, login

I have created an Account, and Contact, and enabled that Contact as a user on Communities in a development sandbox. The user has a valid email, and is using a Customer Community Login license. He has a custom profile, which was created from `Customer Community Login User`, but the custom profile has not been modified in any way yet.

My org email deliverability settings are set to All Emails, but for some reason, when I created the user, no welcome email has been sent.

So, I tried browsing to the Communities site as the user, and resetting the password as the user, but no password reset email was received (and no error messages stating that I wouldn't receive one).

Finally, I followed [these instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_communities_external_member_login_info.htm&type=5), and tried to reset the user's email as an Admin, but there is no Reset Password button for the user:

[image]

The email address for the user is valid, and I'm getting other emails from the org. Why don't I get any emails related to the user's login credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are few steps which you need to make sure are correct and they will surely solve your problem.

1. Make sure your community is in active state and not in Preview mode.
2. Make sure the community user profile is added in the community setting under allowed profile.

You are missing one of above steps.